# C# accessing a class'es member from private static void

Tags: c#, class, static-methods, member

I need to use both "public int" (not 100% sure about it) and "private static void" (100% sure about that!!)

However, I can not access the class'es member data from within the private static void.

Can somebody tell me how to fix this or workaround it?

Thank you very much for the help!

```
namespace MyDLL
{

    public class clsDLL
    {
        ThirdPartyAPI _api = new ThirdPartyAPI();
        double _X = 0;

        //My C# project is a COM DLL that will be called by other applications, so I have chosen "public int" here
        public int open(string uKey)
        {
            int iRet = _api.Open(uKey);
            return iRet;
        }

        //This is a callback that will be called by "_api"
        private static void CallBack_MoveDetected(ref MoveData data, IntPtr userData)
        {
            _X=data.positionX; //this does not work. I can not access "_X" from here.
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That's the whole point of having a static method, it's not tied to any particular instance.

Comment: Why does the method need to be static?  What is `_X`, what does it represent?  Instance members require an instance of the object, static members don't have the context of an instance.  You're going to need to define your business domain in terms of objects (instances) and concepts (static).

Comment: You could pass the instance variable to the static method and add a get property for the instances

Comment: What is the difference between static and not-static? I have never understood it.

Comment: @tmighty Google is your friend.

Comment: @tmighty: Think of the difference between instance and static as the difference between operations on a "Customer" and operations on the *concept* of a "Customer." For example, a Customer has a name, an address, can place orders, etc. These operations require a *specific* Customer in order to make sense. Static operations, on the other hand, wouldn't be in the context of a *specific* Customer, but with the concept of a Customer in general.

Comment: Can you make your variable _X static?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this make any sense, but you could change your class as

```
namespace MyDLL
{
    public class clsDLL
    {
        ThirdPartyAPI _api = new ThirdPartyAPI();
        double _X = 0;

        public double X 
        { 
           get{ return _X;} 
           set{ _X = value;}
        }

        public int open(string uKey)
        {
            int iRet = _api.Open(uKey);
            return iRet;
        }

        private static void CallBack_MoveDetected(ref MoveData data, 
                            IntPtr userData, clsDLL instance)
        {
            instance.X=data.positionX; 
        }
    }
}
```

Returning to your initial problem. No there is no way for a static method to use an instance variable directly without having an instance of the class. Think about it. A static method exists without the need to have any instance declared so, if what you are trying to do was possible in any way, what instance should be the elected one from which the static method reads the value of the variable _X ?

Comment: Thank you. The problem however is that CallBack_MoveDetected is not defined by me, but by the ThirdPartyAPI, so I can not change the arguments to pass it an instance of the class.

Comment: I did not want to make the CallBack_MoveDetected static, but I had to. Else I got a delegate error, and delegates are really beyond my horizon. But I do understand that it should not be static.

Comment: I could get the class from userData somehow, I guess. But that would be even more ugly than my ugly workaround, I think.

Comment: It seems a bit strange that you cannot use a non-static method for the delegate. Perhaps you should show how do you setup the call to this method

Comment: I had to strip my project down really much to make it readable here, but the setup is like this:                 MoveDetected += new MoveDetectedDelegate(Callback_MoveDetected);
                
                IntPtr p;

                p = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(MoveDetected);
                _api.SetMoveCB(p.ToInt32(), IntPtr.Zero);

Comment: What is the API that you're using? Might it have some publicly accessible documentation?

Comment: There is no documentation on the callbacks unfortunately.

Comment: I'll repeat - "What is the API that you're using?"